# How can I make only one UITableView cell can be highlighted when selected?

Tags: uitableview, selection

I want to make only one cell to be highlighted when it's selected.

I can't use UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone because I want other cells to be selectable and can be highlighted in edit mode.

Every comment will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this

Just use next two lines in viewDidLoad and made last cell has very big (enough to cover entire cell) UIButton.

```
self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;
self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```